# How to Save word document in a folder which is created by Directory.CreateDirectory(docfile_path)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, office-interop, com-interop

This block of code throws an error called file name is invalid.

I want to create a folder named as "test" inside this there will be another folder named as today's date "date" , i want to keep the the word document inside this date folder, please help.

```
public string File_path;
public string docfile_path;
public string filename;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

              string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
              string date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

               docfile_path = File_path+ "test" + date;
               Directory.CreateDirectory(docfile_path);

                 filename = docfile_path + "worddoc"+"-" +".docx";


    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
                Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
                try
                {
                    doc = app.Documents.Open(filename);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

                Word.Paragraph oPara1;
                oPara1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
                oPara1.Range.Text = "Test Result";
                oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
                oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
                oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
                oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
                 Word.Paragraph oPara2;
                oPara2 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
                oPara2.Range.Text = "Test Name";
                oPara2.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
                oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
                oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

                doc.SaveAs2(filename);
                doc.Close();
                doc = null;

                app.Quit();
                app = null;

    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and look at your variables. After you recognize what is wrong, the static class `Path` with it's method [Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) should be able to help you fix it.

Comment: I think your problem is that you might be missing a `/` between the directory and the filename. Try `var fileName = Path.Combine(docfile_path, docfile_path + "worddoc"+"-" +".docx");`.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly enough, this code compile and run, but the outcome is not what you probably wanted.

A couple of things is wrong in this code:

1.you cant add strings like that to create a path, a path should be created with the '/' symbol between directories.
this is a legal path:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Games";
```

this is not :

```
string path = @"C:UsersusernameDesktopGames";
```

you can fix it by using the Path.Combine function as follow:

```
docfile_path = Path.Combine(File_path , "test" , date);
```

be sure to this for all path strings (including File_path that is value is not shown in the code above).

2.you should use

```
Document doc = app.Documents.Add();
```

to create a new Word document and not

```
Document doc = new Document();
```

3.you should use a different format for string date, DateTime.ToShortDateString() is dividing the date with the '/' symbol which will create new folders.
try using:

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

4.I don't see any reason for the line

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(filename);
```

You  are trying to open the the file that you intent to create?

here is the code i used:

```
        string File_path = @"C:\Users\yakir\Desktop"; 
        string docfile_path;
        string filename;

        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
        string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

        docfile_path = Path.Combine(File_path , "test" , date);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(docfile_path);

        filename = Path.Combine(docfile_path, "worddoc" + "-" + ".docx");


        Application app = new Application();
        Document doc = app.Documents.Add();

        Paragraph oPara1;
        oPara1 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
        oPara1.Range.Text = "Test Result";
        oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        Paragraph oPara2;
        oPara2 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
        oPara2.Range.Text = "Test Name";
        oPara2.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
        oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        doc.SaveAs2(filename);
        doc.Close();
        doc = null;

        app.Quit();
        app = null;
    }
```